# 'await' end of statement expected syntax error in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 3.6. I have the following code:

```
from darksky.api import DarkSky, DarkSkyAsync
from darksky.types import languages, units, weather

forecast = await darksky.get_forecast(
    latitude, longitude,
    extend=False, # default `False`
    lang=languages.ENGLISH, # default `ENGLISH`
    units=units.AUTO, # default `auto`
    exclude=[weather.MINUTELY, weather.ALERTS] # default `[]`
)
```

Pycharm shows an an error. When I hover over the end of await, it says end of statement expected and when I hover over await, it says unresolved reference 'await'. It shows me an option to import package of 'await' but when I try to import it, the installation fails with the error 'PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:'.

Actually before using Python 3.6, I used 3.7 and there was no such error in 3.7. The only issue was that PyCharm couldn't import packages for weather, units and DarkSky. So I had to switch to Python 3.6 which could import those packages.

Comment: You can't await outside of an async function, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression.

Comment: Verify, if your `[Run] => [Configuration]` points to `Python 3.6`